# Migration from setInterval to requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

I am trying to migrate some old animations that are based on setInterval to requestAnimationFrame, however my updateState function requires some arguments and I can't understand how to pass them with requestAnimationFrame. Here's an example how the old code calls the drawing function:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
     oldValue < newValue ? updateState(oldValue += max/100) : clearInterval(interval);
},16);
```

All examples of rAF show it used like:

```
function updateState() {
    requestAnimFrame( updateState );
}

updateState();
```

How can I pass in my arguments to the updateState function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same you do with `setInterval`, put your call to updateState in a closure.

```
function updateState() {
    requestAnimFrame( function(){
        if( oldValue < newValue ) {
            updateState(oldValue += max/100);
        }
    });

    // The rest of your code
}

updateState();
```